# Why doesn't `git merge <branch> --squash` make a commit?

Tags: git, merge, branch, commit, squash

When doing a normal merge, e.g. `git merge <branch>`, `git` creates a merge commit and updates the `HEAD` of the current branch to that commit.

When doing a squash merge, e.g. `git merge <branch> --squash`, however, it does not make a commit, saying (on a clean merge):

```
Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
```

What's the rationale behind this? To me, this seems like an unexpected difference between a normal merge and a squash merge. It would be more intuitive to me if the **only** difference between a normal merge and a squash merge were that a squash merge squashes commits.

Comment: Hey Luke, please take a look to the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/merging-with-squash?view=vsts

Comment: I read through these docs but didn't see any information about this question specifically.

Comment: Merging doesn’t always creating a commit. You have to pass a flag (or set a setting) to make sure it does.

Comment: Perhaps even more puzzling (or revealing?) is why doesn't `git merge <branch> --squash --commit` make a commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of *why* question really has to be sent to whoever wrote the command in the first place; only they really know.

The underlying implementation is lazy: it goes through the same code path as regular merge but skips writing the file `MERGE_HEAD`, and then exits early to avoid going through the code that would make a merge commit.

If you use the `--no-commit` option, the code goes through nearly the same path.  In fact, the control variable for this is `option_commit`, and setting `--squash` clears `option_commit` as if you ran with `--no-commit`.

If `--squash` *didn't* clear `option_commit`, it looks like the existing path would complain that the automerge failed.  So it *may* simply be laziness.

Answer (score 4):

> What's the rationale behind this?

The draft merge commit message will contain all your squashed messages from the other branch. Something like this:

```
Squashed commit of the following:

commit 2fb77b77f813501ae2c8159e7bf751c216572a57
Author: Your Name <you@example.com>
Date:   Tue May 22 22:47:50 2018 +0200

    Drop baz

commit 894f1ef07af29d25c4716dce9db4402032f854d4
Author: Your Name <you@example.com>
Date:   Tue May 22 22:47:39 2018 +0200

    Fix bar

commit 7f60998ab1949e9e8db9229f9ef9e7c0333cd04f
Author: Your Name <you@example.com>
Date:   Tue May 22 22:47:19 2018 +0200

    Add foo
```

Usually, you will want to customize that message before committing.

---

If you are happy with the default message you could do:

```
git merge <branch> --squash && git commit --no-edit
```

Comment: But `git commit` (with or without `--no-edit`) will indeed finisn the job, so why doesn't `git merge --squash` run `git commit` for you unless you run `git merge --squash --no-commit`? The `--edit` and `--no-edit` options are already passed through as well.

Comment: Why can't this be `git merge <branch> --squash --commit --no-edit`?  The fact that it has to be two separate invocations of git is surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're like me, the problem is you have already merged that branch into master and have forgotten you have done so. It's not updating because the changes and master are identical.

Hope this answers helps someone waste less time than I did.